# Authentication with Azure Active Directory - how to accept user credentials programmatically

Tags: python, authentication, azure, oauth, azure-active-directory

Is there any way to login via web application or web api to Azure Active Directory (with AD credentials) using my own username and password page which is hosted outside of Azure?

From my investigation it seems there is no programmatic way to send username and password to authenticate users with Azure AD (if you hosted an app outside of Azure)
Not sure if they consider this to be a security hole of some sort (i dont think it is it https is enforced?)

Seems like you can only authenticate users by going through the code grant (which means popping out of our application to sign on to an external site).

Ultimately I want to create a python flask api that can authenticate against Azure AD directly if possible.
I have done this in the past (with other auth systems) with the Oauth grant_type=password to send username and pass, but dont think this is supported in Azure AD (correct me if im wrong?)
I know grant_type=client_credentials is supported, but that seems like its service to service auth, which is not quite what im after
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645543.aspx

If its not possible to have a login page hosted outside of Azure for this, is it even possible to have one inside of Azure, seems like from examples here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/bc8af4ff-66e7-4d5b-b3d4-c33d2c55d270#BKMK_Browser
There is no custom login page with a password field .. (only open id logins it seems)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3) (`grant_type=password`) flow **is** supported by Azure Active Directory. However, before using it, consider if it is truly required. As it says in the OAuth 2.0 RFC:

> The resource owner password credentials (i.e., username and password) can be used directly as an authorization grant to obtain an access token.  The credentials should only be used when there is a high degree of trust between the resource owner and the client (e.g., the client is part of the device operating system or a highly privileged application), **and when other authorization grant types are not available (such as an authorization code)**.

If you have determined that the other supported flows will definitely not work for your scenario, then also be sure to follow the second bit of advice in the RFC:

> Even though this grant type requires direct client access to the resource owner credentials, the resource owner credentials are used for a single request and are exchanged for an access token.  This grant type can **eliminate the need for the client to store the resource owner credentials for future use, by exchanging the credentials with a long-lived access token or refresh token**.

(Emphasis added in both cases.)

There's a .NET and ADAL sample on GitHub that uses this flow, and it should be simple enough to implement in Python: https://github.com/AzureADSamples/NativeClient-Headless-DotNet

Edit: You can host your application anywhere you want, it doesn't need to be on Azure. This applies to all flows.

Comment: thanks for the info. I assume the authContext.AcquireToken(todoListResourceId, clientId, uc); call is sending the username and pass ?

Comment: Can i also use this flow and pass in the client_secret? msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645542.aspx . Problem with this is that I dont see a way to change the standard AD login page (besides the images etc you can change within Azure AD settings) you cant prevent it from being shown when calling /authorize

Comment: Yes, `authContext.AcquireToken(todoListResourceId, clientId, uc)` passes in the username and password (in a `UserCredentials` object, but that's just something that is interpreted by ADAL). If you're passing in the client secret, you're not authenticating as a user, but as the application. That would be the [Client Credentials Grant](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-4.4) flow, which is also supported. It's one or the other, not both at the same time.

Comment: And to answer the second comment: when you use the Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant flow, your application is collecting the username and password, and passing it to AAD directly to authenticate. There is no sending the user to AAD sign-in pages.

Comment: The above scenario is exactly the same as mine. I am trying to use the chrome app, Postman, to get the access token. I have 2 users in my tenant. One user has Multi-Factor Authentication (MFA) enabled for singing in while the other does not. When I provide the credentials of the user with MFA enabled, I get an error as "AADSTS50076: The user is required to use multi-factor authentication to access this resource. Please retry with a new authorize request for the resource". I cannot disable MFA for the user and so need to find a way out. Any guidance is highly appreciated.

Comment: @Ashish So are you looking to bypass MFA? Or do you actually want MFA to happen? How would this work, for an MFA-enabled user, if it were up to you?

Comment: @Philippe, MFA is an organization standard which we will implement for all users. Ideally, if I am trying to get the Access token from my company network, I should only be requested to enter my uid/pwd. But for me, every time it is asking for uid/pwd/verification code. Do you think there is an issue with the way my users are setup in Azure AD? MFA should  happen but from, outside my company network. Hope this clarifies my scenario a bit more.

Comment: Do you have federation set up and on-prem MFA? Or are you using Azure MFA? Have you set up conditional access rules such that MFA is only required from your company's IP range? And does this work for you when doing normal sign-ins?

Comment: As a developer, I need to validate your queries from my admin. We have O365 and Azure access via our accounts. As far as I know we are using Azure MFA. When we log into O365 from our network, we are not asked for MFA but for Azure, it's always asked.

Comment: There are threats in the official AzureAD Node repo that this feature is going to be deprecated? Is that the case?

https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-nodejs/pull/99?_pjax=%23js-repo-pjax-container

Comment: I would say it's more of a warning that the undocumented and thus unsupported behaviour you may have discovered and may be using will change at some point in the future. Also note that it is specifically about using Resource Owner Password Credentials (i.e. username/password) with a confidential client, which is, and always has been, unsupported.