# Which options of authentication in Office 365 should I use to access user email?

Tags: rest, azure, outlook, office365, azure-active-directory

This is my first time working with Office 365 APIs. What we wanted to achieve is to retrieve users email from Office 365 and display the content in our Java Web Application.

Few thinks I looked through:

- It is recommended not to use basic authentication but rather OAuth or OpenId
- Rest API is the standard.
- Should we register our application in to Azure AD ? Do we have to use for every new user or is it only a one time setup ?

I would really appreciate it if you point me to any sample source code to refer too. Feel free to suggest me any recommendations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should we register our application in to Azure AD ? Do we have to use for every new user or is it only a one time setup ?

Yes you must register your application to use OAuth, which is required by the REST API. I recommend you register in the Application Registration Portal at http://apps.dev.microsoft.com/. You can login to the ARP with an Office 365 account OR a Microsoft account. This allows you to use the Azure "v2" OAuth model, and to access Outlook.com accounts in addition to Office 365.

Registration is a one-time thing, assuming you want to make your web application multi-tenant.

There's a walkthrough for Java/Spring web app here: https://dev.outlook.com/restapi/tutorial/java

Finished source code here: https://github.com/jasonjoh/java-tutorial

Comment: Thank you! I've also found the following tutorial https://dev.outlook.com/restapi/getstarted on REST API. I'll compare it with the Java code and see which one works best for us. Thanks again.

Comment: Instead of having the window for users to sign on Office365, is there a way to send an api call using their user name and password that is securely stored in our DB? i.e When users login to our system, they use similar credential as Office365 so instead of asking them to login again, can we automatically send their username and password ?

Comment: I haven't done this myself, but I believe the username/password flow is supported by Azure. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26794759/authentication-with-azure-active-directory-how-to-accept-user-credentials-prog. However I'd recommend against it. The idea here would be to have them sign in once to "connect" their Office365 account to your internal account. Once you have refresh token you wouldn't need them to reauthenticate.

Comment: I totally understand why you are against it. However, I wasn't sure for how long we can use the refresh token. We don't want to ask users to login to Office365 every time they logout of our system and then login again. We can def use the refresh token while they are still logged in our system but once they logout of our system we invalidate the session. May be we can try to store the token on server side. Not sure yet.

Comment: I've integrated the auth part but I stuck at "The reply address is not using a secure scheme". I posted another question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39025969/aadsts50011-the-reply-address-is-not-using-a-secure-schemeazure. I appreciate your help.