# AADSTS50011 The reply address is not using a secure scheme[AZURE]

Tags: java, azure, authentication, office365, azure-active-directory

I was following this tutorial https://dev.outlook.com/restapi/tutorial/java in order to walk through the process of creating a simple Java Spring MVC app that retrieves messages in Office 365 or Outlook.com.

What I did so far:

- Registered Our Application on AZURE-365-MAIL-API Registration
- Used appId, appPassword, and redirectUrl in to my application and made a request.

Here the controller class:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/auth")
public class AuthorizeController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/authorize", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public JasonMessage authorize(
        @RequestParam("code") String code,
        @RequestParam("id_token") String idToken,
        @RequestParam("state") UUID state,
        HttpServletRequest request) {
    {
        // Get the expected state value from the session
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        UUID expectedState = (UUID) session.getAttribute("expected_state");
        UUID expectedNonce = (UUID) session.getAttribute("expected_nonce");

        // Make sure that the state query parameter returned matches
        // the expected state
        if (state.equals(expectedState)) {
            session.setAttribute("authCode", code);
            session.setAttribute("idToken", idToken);
        } else {
            session.setAttribute("error", "Unexpected state returned from authority.");
        }

        JasonMessage jasonMessage= new JasonMessage();
        jasonMessage.setStatus("success");
        jasonMessage.setData("id_token",idToken);
        jasonMessage.setData("code",code);
        jasonMessage.setData("state",state);
        return jasonMessage;
    }

}
```

}

Here is also the entry point:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/office365")
public class IndexController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/service/mail",
        method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void Office365(Model model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    UUID state = UUID.randomUUID();
    UUID nonce = UUID.randomUUID();

    // Save the state and nonce in the session so we can
    // verify after the auth process redirects back
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    session.setAttribute("expected_state", state);
    session.setAttribute("expected_nonce", nonce);

    String loginUrl = AuthHelper.getLoginUrl(state, nonce);
    model.addAttribute("loginUrl", loginUrl);




    try {
         response.sendRedirect(loginUrl);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}



public class AuthHelper {


private static final String authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com";
private static final String authorizeUrl = authority + "/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize";

private static String[] scopes = {
        "openid",
        "offline_access",
        "profile",
        "https://outlook.office.com/mail.read"
};

private static String appId = "9489e4b5-875d-4bd7-924b-88b3b562ccc7";
private static String appPassword = "0uPnh7gJi86eSWWwr6E2M3F";
private static String redirectUrl = "http://localhost:8080/controller/auth/authorize";

private static String getAppId() {
    if (appId == null) {
        try {
            loadConfig();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
    return appId;
}
private static String getAppPassword() {
    if (appPassword == null) {
        try {
            loadConfig();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
    return appPassword;
}

private static String getRedirectUrl() {
    if (redirectUrl == null) {
        try {
            loadConfig();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
    return redirectUrl;
}

private static String getScopes() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (String scope: scopes) {
        sb.append(scope + " ");
    }
    return sb.toString().trim();
}

private static void loadConfig() throws IOException {
    String authConfigFile = "auth.properties";
    InputStream authConfigStream = AuthHelper.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(authConfigFile);

    if (authConfigStream != null) {
        Properties authProps = new Properties();
        try {
            authProps.load(authConfigStream);
            appId = authProps.getProperty("appId");
            appPassword = authProps.getProperty("appPassword");
            redirectUrl = authProps.getProperty("redirectUrl");
        } finally {
            authConfigStream.close();
        }
    }
    else {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("Property file '" + authConfigFile + "' not found in the classpath.");
    }
}

public static String getLoginUrl(UUID state, UUID nonce) {

    UriComponentsBuilder urlBuilder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(authorizeUrl);
    urlBuilder.queryParam("client_id", getAppId());
    urlBuilder.queryParam("redirect_uri", getRedirectUrl());
    urlBuilder.queryParam("response_type", "code id_token");
    urlBuilder.queryParam("scope", getScopes());
    urlBuilder.queryParam("state", state);
    urlBuilder.queryParam("nonce", nonce);
    urlBuilder.queryParam("response_mode", "form_post");

    return urlBuilder.toUriString();
}
```

}

Entry URL: localhost:8080/controller/office365/service/mail
I believe the problem is with our redirect url which is **http://localhost:8080/controller/auth/authorize .**

This is the error: 
The reply address 'http://localhost:8080/controller/auth/authorize' isn't using a secure scheme.**

Our application requires authentication so before I use the entry url, I manually login to our application and then hit the entry url. Do I need to put the reply url in a way it won't require authentication ? If that is the case I can simply modify web.xml and create a class to by pass authentication. If that is not the problem, I would appreciate your help.

I've also tried using HTTPS but it caused another error.

Thank you!

Comment: What's giving the error? Azure allows localhost to be non-HTTPS, it's the only time they will allow it.

Comment: actually the local host is more or like this username.hqoffice.domain.com:8080/controller/office365/service/mail. I'm not using http://localhost:8080/

Comment: After I login, I just call username.hqoffice.domain.com:8080/controller/office365/servi‌​ce/mail and it hits Office365 controller and redirect me to login to office365, after successful login (which happens automatically), it is supposed to redirect to AuthorizeController rather it displays that error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Azure will not redirect from an authorization request to a non-HTTPS URL. Localhost is the only exception. You'll need to secure your site with HTTPS and make sure that the redirect you give it is HTTPS.