# Authenticate a user on Azure AD B2C using Graph API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I have created a WebApi app which can create a user on Azure AD B2C tenant using Graph API.

Now the user has to authenticate on Azure AD B2C as the same way I have used like Graph API. I mean a programmatic approach to sign in instead of Microsoft login page. Is it possible to authenticate against  Azure AD B2C using Graph API? If yes can you please suggest me the way to do it.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the reason for sign-in the Azure AD B2C without login? When we integrate Azure AD B2C with the web app, they interact with the **OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow**. This flow redirect the users to the IDP as the specification, more detail about OAuth 2 please check [The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to authenticate an user in azure AD using graph API. Graph API provides methods to various AD related operations on the users, signed on user, groups, directory roles, policies and so on. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations

Comment: No problem.hope you were able to complete your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You can programmatically authenticate users against Azure AD using a certain call but MS refuses to officially support the method in libraries, despite it existing for over 4 years.

For node, the denied pull request is here: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-nodejs/pull/99?_pjax=%23js-repo-pjax-container

The code repo referenced in the pull is here: https://github.com/testdouble/azure-activedirectory-library-for-nodejs/tree/client_secret_optional

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26794759/authentication-with-azure-active-directory-how-to-accept-user-credentials-prog

Comment: https://medium.com/@kevinle/securing-nodejs-rest-with-azure-active-directory-95379288a717