# Does Azure AD provide an API method to validate a user programmatically?

Tags: php, azure, single-sign-on, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I want to validate Azure AD users through both a web app and a native mobile app, though Azure AD isn't the only IdP that I'm using.

I've read the [OAuth2 article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code) but I'm having trouble tracking down an API method to validate against a user. [One answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26795582/145190) notes you can pass `username` and `password` parameters when you fetch the token, but it doesn't seem to validate against that.

There's an example of DotNet solution but I'm not familiar with .NET - tried running it and ran into a System.TypeLoad Exception (`Could not load type of field 'Microsoft.Owin.Security.ActiveDirectory.WsFedMetadataRetriever:CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate5'`)

I've previously tried to setup a SimpleSAML solution but the downside is that for native apps it requires extra work and may not be suitable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I recommend you redirect the users to the Azure AD login page.**

You technically can try to validate the user by using the Resource Owner Password Credentials grant. But it will not work always.

This involves you making a POST request to the OAuth token endpoint with form data similar to this:

```
grant_type=password&username=user@example.com&password=Password&client_id=your-client-id&client_secret=your-client-secret&resource=resource-you-want-the-token-for
```

The resource could be `https://graph.windows.net` since you have access to that by default. If the result is successful, then yes, the user exists and the credentials are valid.

But if it fails, it can happen because:

- The user does not exist
- The password is wrong
- The user has multi-factor authentication turned on
- The user is a federated user (from on-prem AD), and authentication must be done via ADFS

So it just simply cannot work in some cases.

Comment: Are there any solutions to if they have MFA turned on? And can you elaborate on "federated user from on-prem AD" - what do you mean by that

Comment: And in testing, seems like what you advised works! Though I'm curious about the above mentioned. Additionally, what would you suggest as the most reliable solution? Just have the Microsoft login page so the user can login themselves, or is this also prone to the 2 clauses above?

Comment: Using the Microsoft log in page is my recommendation. If the user comes back with a valid id token, then they signed in successfully.

Comment: By on-prem users, I mean that Azure AD supports the scenario where we sync Active Directory users from the organisations intranet to Azure AD, so they can use the same account for cloud services as well. Depending on how that is done, the Microsoft login page might need to redirect the user to login at their organisation's ADFS server.

Comment: Here is also an article discussing the downsides of this approach: https://www.scottbrady91.com/OAuth/Why-the-Resource-Owner-Password-Credentials-Grant-Type-is-not-Authentication-nor-Suitable-for-Modern-Applications