# C# SSO login.microsoftonline.com/o365 back-end

Tags: c#, asp.net, single-sign-on, office365, azure-active-directory

I know it is not the best practice but I need to do SSO in the back-end with the username and password of the user (the username and password are saved in a table) and when the user clicks on the link of my site will open the portal Office 365 already with the logged in user, is it possible to do this?

I have tried with WebClient but it does not execute javascript.

Comment: How are planning to get username and password of the user?

Comment: So you have plain text passwords of the user which you will use to auto login user. That's the biggest security hole in your system. Even if somehow you can achieve what you want to it is not recommended.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya: why is biggest security hole?

Comment: Storing passwords of user in plain text is the main issue. No application does that. It's illegal too. Why would user use your application if he know that you can use their password at your will? Would you use any such application? If your application gets compromised, passwords go into hackers hands then you can only imagine how big the disaster would be.

Comment: You need to check if office 365 offers an API which can login user with username and password provided to it. Otherwise you need to post username and password to the login form of office 365. I am not sure how complex that would be. You can do manual login via browser using active directory account and understand the flow before writing code.

Comment: First off, I wish you do not do this. But if you still want to ignore the warnings that everyone gives and also make a system that does not support users with MFA or who are federated users, then yes, there is the Password grant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47104774/1658906. But it is limited, and really should not be used.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do what you are looking to do.

The only way for a user to sign in to Office 365 is through an interactive sign-in where the user sign ins.

What you are proposing (which, again, is not possible) is not only not "best practice", it is a security risk and you should do everything in your power to dissuade those who think this is an acceptable approach to keep usernames and passwords in plain text in a database.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like either vanilla OIDC (instead of the 'Microsoft Identity Platform') or the (Microsoft) 'Graph API' might be a better bet.