# Validating a service account user via Azure AD

Tags: .net, azure, .net-core, azure-active-directory

So we have a scenario in AWS where the service account user (AD User) needs to be validated and authorized. Check credentials then checks if user belongs to a group.

The second bit is fairly trivial however the first bit is proving difficult.

I don't want a token. I want to validate the user sign-in credentials like I can do via .net standard:

```
            using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, server, domain + "\\" + creds[1],
                new NetworkCredential(string.Empty, userCredsSecured.password).Password))
            {
                bool isValid = false;
                try
                {
                    isValid = pc.ValidateCredentials(creds[1],
                        new NetworkCredential(string.Empty, userCredsSecured.password).Password);
```

I know active directory and Azure AD are not the same thing. However, how can I achieve the validation of credentials or authenticating a user.

I tried "hacking the sign-in" by obtaining a token using a users sign in credentials, however that is not optimal as it will require additional permissions on the Azure AD Enterprise App Reg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To verify the user account credentials and check if the user belongs to a group, check the below:**

- Azure AD doesn't have any direct API to validate the user credentials.
- Hence you can make use of ROPC flow, but this is not recommended by Azure AD due to security issues.
- ROPC flow generates the token if the credentials are valid and later you can make use of the token to check if the user belongs to the group.

For example:

```cs
result = await context.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientId, new UserPasswordCredential("xxx@contoso.com", Password));
```

But ROPC flow does not work if the user account is enabled with MFA. Check this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/v2-oauth-ropc) for more details.

You can generate the token by passing resource as `https://graph.microsoft.com/` so by using the token you can **check if the user belongs to a group like below**:

```json
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/UserID/memberOf?$filter=id eq 'GroupID'
```

[image]

**Reference:**

[php - Does Azure AD provide an API method to validate a user programmatically? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47104334/does-azure-ad-provide-an-api-method-to-validate-a-user-programmatically) by Junnas